# Alfresco association

Tags: associations, alfresco, conceptual

I am trying to understand the Alfresco associations. I have understood the concept behind peer association as well as parent child association with examples.

I am referring their official docs example (peer association) : http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/tasks/dev-extensions-content-models-tutorials-add-association.html

**Screenshot :**

[image]

**Question:** I am not following how *mandatory* and *many* parameters can be used within *source*? Most of examples, I have seen, those are set to same as target. Can anybody explain the use-case where I can set *many* is *true* in source and *false* in target with real use-case/example?

Answer (score 1):

There are many scenarios where many is false in source and true in target.You can check existing alfresco content model for same.Below is link for same.

https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition-old/blob/master/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/contentModel.xml

Apart from that regarding association , you ccan find more details on below link.

https://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/concepts/metadata-model-assoc.html

Comment: Hi @Krutik, thanks for your answer but can you give any real word example where source multiple is necessary? I still can't understand how can be source multiple? Only children (in case of child associations) or related objects (in case of peer associations) can be multiple. How can source multiple?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a Contract and you want to associate it with a Customer. This is a Many-to-One relationship. A Contract is associated with only one Customer (target, many=false) but a Customer can have many Contracts (source, many=true).

Comment: Hi @Jeff, Thanks for your response, I agree on this. Now, my question is do you think is it's really necessary? Because I can achieve it with One-to-Many with Customer as a source and Contract as a Target. What does make sense to have bi-directional relationships? Any real examples?

Comment: Cool, glad this answered your question. Don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Regarding your "does it make sense" question, that's completely up to you and your requirements.

Comment: No, it does not depend on my requirements, my question is how can it be having worth in alfresco concept? There must be real world example where we need it.